Can I use a 16 MHz HSE for USB and USB DFU on an STM32F103?
I'm working on a PCB with an STM32F103C8 and a 16 MHz HSE.
USB FS is working as intended so far (I can send USB HID keystrokes).
I haven't tried flashing it using USB DFU yet.
I read in PM0075 (page 9) and RM0008 (page 62), however, that

The USART peripheral operates with the internal 8 MHz oscillator (HSI).
The CAN and USB OTG FS, however, can only function if an external 8 MHz, 14.7456 MHz or 25 MHz clock (HSE) is present.

What does this mean?
Does it mean that I can't use USB at all if I'm using a 16MHz HSE.
Does it mean that I can't use USB DFU to flash the MCU?
(As far as I know the STM32F103C8 doesn't even have USB OTG FS, only USB FS.)

The STM32F103C8 built-in system bootloader does not support DFU.
So you can't use DFU. The crystal is thus irrelevant.
The quotes you refer from Page 62 of RM and Page 9 of PM0075 are about "Connectivity Line" devices F105 and F107. The F103C8 is a "Medium density performance line" device and Page 61 of RM says you have system bootloader on USART1 only.
If you first program the MCU with a custom bootloader that supports DFU, then it's up to you to make your bootloader to use any frequency crystal that is possible to use with USB.
And yes you can use 16 MHz crystal.
But if you feed 16 MHz to PLL, the only supported frequency where you get USB working is 48 MHz. If you want to run the MCU faster, you anyway need to divide down the 16 MHz with the PLL input prescaler to 8 MHz so you might as well use 8 MHz crystal. The only two frequencies from PLL out that work with USB are 48 MHz and 72 MHz.
As 16 MHz crystals are more difficult to work with than 8 MHz crystals, there is no benefit from 16 MHz crystal unless you want a smaller crystal and are able to choose it correctly so the circuit has enough safety factor in the gain margin to start up and run properly.

Yes, I was talking about flashing the MCU with a custom USB DFU bootloader. I understand from your answer that that does work?

@étale-cohomology You never said using a custom bootloader. Your custom bootloader can do anything with the hardware that is possible. Including making the DFU yourself with USB.
